# Bootstrap typeahead with SODA data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, soda

I'm attempting to use the bootstrap typahead, with a SODA endpoint for a datasource. The SODA endpoint returns a JSON array, and can use simple query strings to query it.

Example of an endpoint:
`https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/earthquakes.json?region=Washington`
Taken from: http://dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started/

In this case, `Washington` is what the user might type in the input.

Example of JSON returned using `Washington` as an example:
`[ {
  "region" : "Washington",
  "source" : "uw",
  "location" : {
    "needs_recoding" : false,
    "longitude" : "-120.0137",
    "latitude" : "47.3452"
  },
  "magnitude" : "3.3",
  "number_of_stations" : "38",
  "datetime" : "2012-09-13T17:33:45",
  "earthquake_id" : "60451342",
  "depth" : "12.70",
  "version" : "1"
}
, {
  "region" : "Washington",
  "source" : "uw",
  "location" : {
    "needs_recoding" : false,
    "longitude" : "-122.4432",
    "latitude" : "46.5543"
  },
  "magnitude" : "1.1",
  "number_of_stations" : "31",
  "datetime" : "2012-09-13T11:52:57",
  "earthquake_id" : "60451197",
  "depth" : "16.60",
  "version" : "2"
} ]`

Sorry if formatting of the JSON is weird.

So far, I have been unable to get the typeahead to work, nor could find sufficient documentation on how to retrieve such data.

Comment: What do you want to see in the typeahead? A list of regions or some other field for each region?

Comment: In this case, a list of regions. The typeahead might return the list of regions as the user types, which will finally settle on `Washington`.

Comment: Does SODA offer a list of possible regions? That what you need to use, rather then getting data for a region.

Comment: I could probably query the data source for a list of possible regions, then use that in the updater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call the url when user choose from the options, you can use `updater`

```
$("#sourceInput").typeahead({
   source:function(query,process){
      var url = 'https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/earthquakes.json?region=' + query;
      $.getJSON(url,function(resp){
        process(resp)
      });
   },
   updater: function(item){
      var url = 'https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/earthquakes.json?region=' + item;
      $.getJSON(url,function(resp){
        //do something with json response
      });
      //return the item for the input
      return item;
   }
});
```

Comment: The issue is, I need the source to be checked against the url as the user typed, rather than a pre-defined list of regions.